# How to prove this deduction?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

When I was working with mathematics, I encountered with a problem.

For a given $A,B\in \mathbb{R}$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$, I have to solve the equations below (where $U_i\in\left\{0,1\right\}$):

$$A = \frac{U_1}{1}+\frac{U_2}{2}+\frac{U_3}{3}+\cdots+\frac{U_N}{N}$$

$$B = \frac{U_1}{N}+\frac{U_2}{N-1}+\frac{U_3}{N-2}+\cdots+\frac{U_N}{1}$$

From my point of view, I thought it has a unique solution for each $U_i$. However, I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Constraints are $U_i\in\left\{0,1\right\}$。

Comment: It is not clear if U can take on any value in [0,1] or only 0 or 1.  If  U can take any value in [ 0,1] there are an infinity of solutions. On the other hand, if U can only take the values 0 or 1, there may or may be not a solution, depending on A and B (is IA the same as A?)

Comment: U can only take 0 or 1. Given A and B ensure that there is a solution.

Comment: Obviously $A$ and $B$ must be rational numbers in order for a solution to exist, so we cannot ensure that there is a solution for $A = \pi$ and $B = 1$, say. Also For $N = 1$ and $A = 2$ we know that there is no solution. Etc etc. So 'ensure that there is a solution' sounds a bit strange.

Comment: But maybe you mean something like that $A, B$ and $N$ are chosen so that we know that there exist at least 1 solution and the question is how to show that it is unique? In that case please edit the question to include the information that $A, B$ and $N$ are such that at least one solution exists, because these combination are quite special

Comment: But if that is the correct interpretation the question is quite interesting! Maybe for some $A$ and $N$ the $U_i$ are determined uniquely by first equation alone, even.

Comment: A search term when looking for more information might be 'Egyptian fractions'